# How to detect "[" + digit + "]" in a string and find the highest digit

Tags: c++

I'm trying to detect the highest digit found in square brackets in a string.

For example,

```
std::string str = "a[1]b[7]cde[8]fg[3]h[5]";
int highest = findHighestDigit(str);
std::cout << highest << '\n';
```

I want the result to be `8` in this case.

All I can think of now is to manually check from `[0]` to `[9]` in a for loop.

Would there be more elegant solution?

Comment: Something like `int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); size_t n = 0; while ((n = str.find ("[", n)) != std::string::npos) { int val = std::stoi (str.substr (++n)); if (val > max) max = val;}`?

Comment: First figure out how to detect a digit in square brackets. Then consume the string and keep the largest one.

Comment: You may implement a finite automaton that stores the highest found result. That requires a single traversal.

Comment: If you want a more declarative way to do this: If starting with a character string (like argv[1]) you could: https://onlinegdb.com/ByEG6XtmB  and if startting with a string you could: https://onlinegdb.com/Skc7JVF7H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of David C. Rankin is already the "more and good" C++ solution.

I would like to add the "Full blown"-Algorithm plus Regex" C++ solution ;-)

This is mayby the overkill in terms of time and memory, but a very elegant C++ solution.

The heart of all ist to use the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. This iterator has been made exactly for the given pupose. Match some pattern, give me the result and select the max element.

We define a regex, that will match the digit in brackets. Something like "[\d]". Since we want to return something with the `std::sregex_token_iterator`, we build a group around the digit: "[(\d)]".

Ok, now we can iterate over all digits in the string. And because we can do this now, we can use the standard algorithm `std::max_element` to find the max value.

And to show this on the screen we can also use an algorithm: `std::copy` in combination with `std::ostream_itarator`.

All this adds up to

```
std::copy_n(std::max_element(std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator()), 1, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

And because stuffing everything in one line is not so nice, I will press enter here and there and add many comments:

```
    std::copy_n(                         // We wan to copy one value from a range to std::cout
        std::max_element(                // Find the max element in a range
            std::sregex_token_iterator(  // The range starts with the begin of the list of tokens
                str.begin(),             // Start reading tokens from begin of str
                str.end(),               // Read all tokens up to the end of the string
                re,                      // This is the token that we are looking for. A digit in brackets
                1),                      // We want to get the matched result
            std::sregex_token_iterator() // Find all tokens up until lats
        ),
        1,                               // Even, if there are more than one max value (equal values possible), return only 1
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") // Print on screen
    );
```

Now we have eveything in one statement, using algorithms all over the place.

To be clear again, it basically adds no value and is rather hardcore. But it is "full blown" C++  ;-)

Please see below the fully executable code (MSVS 19, C++17):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// Regex for one digit in brackets
const std::regex re(R"(\[(\d)\])");

int main()
{
    // The source string to evaluate
    std::string str = "a[1]b[7]cde[8]fg[3]h[5]";

    // Step 1: Find all digits in bracket and output them
    std::cout << "\nStep 1:  Iterate over all digits and display them\n";
    for (std::sregex_token_iterator sti(str.begin(), str.end(), re, 1); sti != std::sregex_token_iterator(); ++sti)
        std::cout << *sti << "\n";

    // Step 2:  Use an algorithm an COPY to ststd::cout
    std::cout << "\n\nStep 2:  We can also iterate over the values and copy them to std::cout\n";
    std::copy(
        std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, 1),
        std::sregex_token_iterator(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
    );

    // Step 3: Iteration clear now. Use max_element to find max in range of digits
    std::cout << "\n\nStep 3:  We know how to iterate. Find max_element\n"
        << *std::max_element(std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator());

    // Step 4: All in one solution
    std::cout << "\n\nStep 4:  All in one\n";
    std::copy_n(std::max_element(std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator()), 1, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    // Step 5: All in one solution. More readable version with comments
    std::cout << "\n\nStep 5:  All in one and mare readable\n";
    std::copy_n(                         // We wan to copy one value from a range to std::cout
        std::max_element(                // Find the max element in a range
            std::sregex_token_iterator(  // The range starts with the begin of the list of tokens
                str.begin(),             // Start reading tokens from begin of str
                str.end(),               // Read all tokens up to the end of the string
                re,                      // This is the token that we are looking for. A digit in brackets
                1),                      // We want to get the matched result
            std::sregex_token_iterator() // Find all tokens up until lats
        ),
        1,                               // Even, if there are more than one max value (equal values possible), return only 1
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") // Print on screen
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow this works perfectly. Can I ask what `const std::regex re(R"(\[(\d)\])");` exactly means? What is `R`? And `(\d)` is for integer right? What if I want to detect a digit between two `d`s instead of `[]`?

Comment: How can I get the result variable? not just print to a console?

Comment: You can get the resulting string with ````*std::max_element(std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator());```` (see Step 3). This will be a string. Use ````std::stoi````to convert to integer. R starts a raw string literal. Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal. Correct, \d is for digits. And yes, any other match also possible. I do not fully understand " What if I want to detect a digit between two ds instead of []", Can you please explain with example? Maybe (R"(\d(\d)\d)"? Would find the 2 in 123.

Answer (score 3):

A more C++ solution (elegant is somewhat arbitrary), could be crafted with the `std::basic_string` functions `.find()`, `.substr()` and `stoi()`. Simply looping using `.find()` to locate each occurrence of `"["`, then using `.substr()` to retrieve the characters following `"["` and passing to `stoi()` to attempt the conversion to `int`. A reference for each can be found at [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

For example:

```
int findHighestDigit (const std::string& str)
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();  /* set max to lowest value */
    size_t n = 0;                               /* initialize index zero */

    while ((n = str.find ("[", n)) != std::string::npos) {  /* if "[" found */
        int val = std::stoi (str.substr (++n));        /* get following int */
        if (val > max)        /* check if int > max, update max accordingly */
            max = val;
    }

    return max;     /* return max */
}
```

(**note:** you should wrap the `stoi()` call and the check of `val > max` in a `try {...} catch {...}` exception handler to handle the case where `"["` is not followed by optional whitespace and a digit -- that is left to you)

Putting it together in a short example using your string, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int findHighestDigit (const std::string& str)
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();  /* set max to lowest value */
    size_t n = 0;                               /* initialize index zero */

    while ((n = str.find ("[", n)) != std::string::npos) {  /* if "[" found */
        int val = std::stoi (str.substr (++n));        /* get following int */
        if (val > max)        /* check if int > max, update max accordingly */
            max = val;
    }

    return max;     /* return max */
}

int main (void) {

    std::string str = "a[1]b[7]cde[8]fg[3]h[5]";
    int highest = findHighestDigit(str);

    if (highest != std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
        std::cout << "max: " << highest << '\n';
    else
        std::cerr << "error: highest returned INT_MIN\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/maxbracketint
max: 8
```